# How to let a user modify a fact without activating a certain rule?

Tags: clips

I wonder if it is somehow possible to have a construct, such that a user can modify a rule without triggering a rule. So my minimal example:

```
(defrule A-has-B
   (A B)
=>
   (assert (A-has-B)
)

(assert (A A))

f-1 (A A)
```

Now, I would like to modify (A A) to (A B) without triggering the rule "A-has-B".

First I thought about something like:

```
(defrule A-has-B
   (A B)
   (not (exists (usercontrol on)))
=>
   (assert (A-has-B)
)
```

But after retracting '(usercontrol on)' the rule fires.

Maybe, somebody can tell me whether it's possible or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to disable a pattern from being matched by a fact.